# Is there a way to insert JQuery/Javascript in Google Optimize?

Tags: jquery, google-optimize, abtest

I am adding jQuery to my website with Google Optimize. And I get this error in the console:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin
>   provided ('') does not match the recipient window's origin
>   ('')

Is there a way to get around this?

This is my jQuery:

```
$('#ab_target').click(function(){
  window.localStorage.setItem('frequency','5')
})
```

Comment: Could you please add more details, how and when your code is invoked with Google Optimize?

Comment: Yes of course. On the front end with google optimize, I added a button with html with an id="ab_target". This button needs to have the frequency set to 5 because in my back end, frequency determines the amount of an item you are purchasing which is what I am testing. So the JQuery sets frequency in the local storage to 5 so that the backend code will be able to identify the button frequency

Comment: Do you get the error when the experiment is being applied, or when the button is clicked, and this added function is running?